# Creating an automatic countdown based on a time list in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, time

In my Program, I have a list containing times across the day in chronological order. I want to create a function that loops through the list, converts the times in string format to datetime format  and checks which time hasn't passed yet. Once that time is found, it is subtracted from the current time and the remainder is returned. That remainder will then be displayed in a label.

To illustrate this, this is a simplified version of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = tk.Tk()


time_list = ['04:18 AM', '12:31 PM', '03:52 PM', '07:16 PM', '08:39 PM']

def calc_countdown():
     loop_label = tk.Label(window)
     current_time = time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
     
     loop_label.after(1000,calc_countdown)


lbl_time_left = tk.Label(window,text="Time left : ",)
lbl_time_left.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

display_time_left = tk.Label(window,text="50 minutes 5 seconds")
display_time_left.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew")

calc_countdown()
window.mainloop()
```

So from this, if I run the code at 2:00 pm, the function will find the difference between 3:52pm  and 2:00 pm and return the remainder. What I thought of doing was to iterate through the list and subtract each time  in it  with the current time and the one with the lowest difference is returned and displayed. But I wasn't sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime` module to get the time and calculate them.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

window = tk.Tk()

time_list = ['04:18 AM', '12:31 PM', '03:52 PM', '07:16 PM', '08:39 PM']
# convert them to datetime object
time_struct_list = [datetime.strptime(i, "%I:%M %p") for i in time_list]

def calc_countdown():
    current_time = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%I:%M:%S %p"), "%I:%M:%S %p")
    # also get it when time > '08:39 PM'
    nearest_time = next((i for i in time_struct_list if i > current_time), datetime.strptime('01-02 04:18 AM', "%m-%d %I:%M %p"))

    text.set("{} hours {} minutes {} seconds".format(*str(nearest_time - current_time).split(":")))
    window.after(1000, calc_countdown)


text = tk.StringVar()
lbl_time_left = tk.Label(window, text="Time left : ", )
lbl_time_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

display_time_left = tk.Label(window, textvariable=text)
display_time_left.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

window.after(0, calc_countdown)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you explain what the  line that declared the  nearest_time does? I've never used next() before and I'm not familiar with that sort of code structure.

Comment: @Abdulrahman This is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is to get the first element of the generator.

Comment: Ok Thnx for the solution